# Android SDK and AVD Manager only shows latest version (not showing versions 5 or 6)?

Tags: android

I want to develop an app targeting Android version 2.1 (6) and above so I have started the SDK and AVD Manager. In Available packages, for version 2.1 it shows Update-1 (version code 7) but not versions 5 and 6, which I guess are superseded.

If I install that version and compile against it, does it mean that handsets on version 6 cannot install my app from the Market? If so, how do I install the version 6 library or any version that is missing from the list, such as the 2.0.1 Eclair build? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I answered my own question but have left it on here in case anybody else does what I did. There is a checkbox, Display Updates Only, which was ticked so I was not seeing all versions.