# Android SDK not showing SDKs for Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator

Today when I wanted to install SDK Api level 8 i.e Android 2.2. To my surprise I could not find the 2.2 Sdk in it. Has Google stopped the support of 2.2 or is it some kind of bug that I have encountered. Here is a printScreen that shows the problem
[image]

I dont want to update my SDK tools and Platform-tools because after updating it my AppEngine Connected Project is not working properly.

Comment: That picture isn't fuzzy at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Chris solution:

You can download SDK 2.2 (Froyo rev3) from this URL

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.2_r03-linux.zip

Create a folder 'android-8' under your Android SDK installation dir and extract the zip there:

```
/android_sdk/platforms/android-8/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate : [Android SDK and AVD Manager only shows latest version (not showing versions 5 or 6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090433/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-only-shows-latest-version-not-showing-versions-5-or)

Uncheck the show updates/new checkbox.

Comment: In a sensible world that would be the answer, but it is not.

Comment: Just noticed this my self, my bad! Mine isn't showing any versions below 10 either

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to be reshuffling things between the various versions of the repository.xml file which is the source of the list you see there.  Since this may well happen again, I think the long-term solution is to try looking for variations of the filename, ie, repository-#.xml until you find one with links to the SDK version you want.  Then download and unpack it manually.